# Determine unique values across multiple arrays (with `d3.nest`)

Tags: d3.js, nested, reduce

I have a large dataset in which each entry has this shape:

```
{
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'bar',
    tags: ['baz', 'qux']
}
```

I know how to find, say, all unique `name`s in my dataset using [`d3.nest`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nests):

```
d3.nest()
    .key(d => d.name)
    .rollup(d => d[0])
    .entries(data)
    .map(d => d.key);
```

How can I find all unique `tag`s in my dataset, preferably using `d3.nest()`? I could roll my own reducer, but would prefer to stick to d3 paradigms if possible.

Comment: Do you really need it using `d3.nest()`. There is a 1 line vanilla solution for this.

Comment: Nope. I answered my own silly question below. Thanks @GerardoFurtado.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sometimes it's better to just skip the library and roll your own answer. It's as simple as:

```
let allTags = Object.keys(data.reduce((acc, d) => {
    d.tags.forEach(n => acc[n] = true);
    return acc;
}, {}));
```

Maybe that will help someone in the future.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯